# Why did Heroku stop using doozer?

Tags: heroku, high-availability, doozer

I heard that Heroku stopped using Doozer or at least is not using it much anymore. For strong consistency and high availability what did Heroku replace Doozer with and why? What were the shortcomings of Doozer that the replacement addressed?

Comment: Unless someone from Heroku has made a public statement explaining why, I don't see any way that this can be answered.